# Directory listing is slow when doing it in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

Hello StackOverflow members!

I am trying to run the following command:

```
REM the below line lists the folder names that are to be read
FOR /F "TOKENS=* DELIMS=" %%d in (%start_dir%\folder_list.txt) DO (
    ECHO Entering into: %%d Directory
    REM The below line lists the folders and all of it's subfolders. It than outputs it to a file.

        FOR /F "TOKENS=* DELIMS=" %%e in ('DIR /s "%work_dir%\%%d"') DO (
           ECHO %%e>>%start_dir%\tmp_folder\%%d.size
        )
)
```

The code above works.

Here is the problem: If I have folder that is only a few GB in size, it is fine.

If I have a folder that is above 100GB the script will take about an hour to output the DIR /S>>%%d command.

When I do a run on an individual folder that is about 150GB: Dir /s "150GB_Folder">>dir_ouput_file.txt It completes in about 6-10 seconds.

My question is: Why does it take an hour to output the the DIR /S>>whatever.txt from within a script and it only takes seconds when it is not in a script?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: But why are you writing the output of `DIR /s` line by line to begin with? Why not just do `DIR /s "%work_dir%\%%d" >%start_dir%\tmp_folder\%%d.size`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a bug in `for` where parsing a large number of lines with a command causes huge delays.
The solution is to create a file with the information and then read the file.

```
REM the below line lists the folder names that are to be read
FOR /F "TOKENS=* DELIMS=" %%d in (%start_dir%\folder_list.txt) DO (
    ECHO Entering into: %%d Directory
    REM The below line lists the folders and all of it's subfolders. It than outputs it to a file.

DIR /s "%work_dir%\%%d" >%temp%\temp.tmp

        FOR /F "TOKENS=* DELIMS=" %%e in (%temp%\temp.tmp) DO (
           ECHO %%e>>%start_dir%\tmp_folder\%%d.size
        )
del %temp%\temp.tmp
)
```

Comment: 1+,I've never heard of!

Comment: That worked really well. I figured that it was some kind of bug but I was not 100% sure. Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: I think I understand what you are talking about but I'm not sure if your wording is correct, or perhaps I'm missing something. A `FOR /F` loop doesn't parse *files*, it parses lines of text. I take it the issue is with the number of lines produced by the output of the command in the IN clause (which in this particular case happens to be `DIR`) – that would probably make more sense (to me anyway).